# MySQL INNER/LEFT JOIN on 3 tables, where records in 3rd table might not exist

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I've got a problem that I can't seem to figure out after a bunch of failed attempts.

I've got three tables that I need to do a join on for some reporting, and in the 3rd table a record might not exist. But if the record in the 3rd table doesn't exist, I need to report a null value for the data that comes from the 3rd table and get all records that match the other conditions.

Stripped down to the relevant columns, here are the table structures:

**members** - *this table holds all members that register to a website*

```
| memberId  | insertDate          |
| ==========|=====================|
| 1         | 2013-08-01 18:18:16 |
| 2         | 2013-08-02 18:18:16 |
| 3         | 2013-08-03 18:18:16 |
| 4         | 2013-08-04 18:18:16 |
| 5         | 2013-08-05 18:18:16 |
```

**registration_steps** - *this table holds the progress of the registration processes and whether the registration was completed or not*

```
| memberId  | completed |
| ==========|===========|
| 1         | 1         |
| 2         | 1         |
| 3         | 1         |
| 4         | 0         |
| 5         | 1         |
```

**purchases** - *this table holds, well.. purchases*

```
| memberId  | insertDate          |
| ==========|=====================|
| 1         | 2013-08-02 18:18:16 |
| 1         | 2013-08-03 17:18:16 |
| 1         | 2013-08-03 18:18:16 |
| 5         | 2013-08-07 18:18:16 |
```

This is the query I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT `m`.`memberId`,
       DATE(`m`.`insertDate`) AS `regDate`,
       COUNT(`p`.`memberId`) AS `totalTransactions`,
       DATE(MIN(`p`.`insertDate`)) AS `firstPurchaseDate`,
       DATE(MAX(`p`.`insertDate`)) AS `latestPurchaseDate`,
       DATEDIFF(DATE(MIN(`p`.`insertDate`)), DATE(`m`.`insertDate`)) AS `daysBetweenRegAndFirstPurchase`
  FROM `db`.`members` `m`
       INNER JOIN `db`.`registration_steps` `r` ON `m`.`memberId` = `r`.`memberId` 
       INNER JOIN `db`.`purchases` `p` ON `m`.`memberId` = `p`.`memberId`
 WHERE `m`.`insertDate` BETWEEN '2013-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-07-31 23:59:59'
   AND `r`.`completed` = 1
GROUP BY `m`.`memberId`
;
```

It shows me everything I want but the members with a missing record in table purchases.

Here is what I get:

```
| memberId  | regDate             | totalTransactions | firstPurchaseDate   | latestPurchaseDate  | daysBetweenRegAndFirstPurchase |
| ==========|=====================|===================|=====================|=====================|================================|
| 1         | 2013-08-01 18:18:16 | 3                 | 2013-08-02 18:18:16 | 2013-08-03 18:18:16 | 1                              |
| 5         | 2013-08-05 18:18:16 | 1                 | 2013-08-07 18:18:16 | 2013-08-07 18:18:16 | 2                              |
```

But what I need is:

```
| memberId  | regDate             | totalTransactions | firstPurchaseDate   | latestPurchaseDate  | daysBetweenRegAndFirstPurchase |
| ==========|=====================|===================|=====================|=====================|================================|
| 1         | 2013-08-01 18:18:16 | 3                 | 2013-08-02 18:18:16 | 2013-08-03 18:18:16 | 1                              |
| 2         | 2013-08-02 18:18:16 | 0                 | NULL                | NULL                | -1                             |
| 3         | 2013-08-03 18:18:16 | 0                 | NULL                | NULL                | -1                             |
| 5         | 2013-08-05 18:18:16 | 1                 | 2013-08-07 18:18:16 | 2013-08-07 18:18:16 | 2                              |
```

In order to achieve this, I tried to change the second inner join to a left join, a left outer join and put the where conditions to the first inner join condition. However, I wasn't able to get the desired result. *(Must admit I interupted a few VERY long running queries that might have been correct(?) though (total count for members in real scenario is about 20k).)*

Anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From where `totalTransactions` come from (`COUNT(`t`.`id`) AS `totalTransactions`,`)?

Comment: there you go.. comes also from purchases table. thanks for spotting

Comment: Try `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @DipeshParmar As said, I tried to change the 2nd inner join to left join, a left outer join and also to put the where conditions to the first inner join condition

Comment: @eyecatchUp i am saying replace all inner join with left outer join...did you tried that..???

Comment: only tried left join on both. and left join on first and left outer join on 2nd. but not yet left outer join on both. executing now.. seems to be one of the long running ones..

Comment: 241.333 execution time.. wow.  @DipeshParmar Could you post that as an answer, so I can accept it as correct? :) Thanks!

Comment: @eyecatchUp "left join" and "left outer join" are the same things. If you say you saw different results by adding/deleting "outer" keyword, it's most likely that your tests were not done right. Probably due to different data.

Comment: @jaeheung thanks for clarification. however, data were the same. so, probably my left join tries where simply those I interupted due to the execution time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the all the result from the `member` table you need to `left join` other table and add `group by` for the `member` table.

**Sample**

```
FROM `db`.`members` `m`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `db`.`registration_steps` `r` ON `m`.`memberId` = `r`.`memberId` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `db`.`purchases` `p` ON `m`.`memberId` = `p`.`memberId`
```

**LEFT [ OUTER ]**

Specifies that all rows from the left table not meeting the join condition are included in the result set, and output columns from the other table are set to NULL in addition to all rows returned by the inner join.

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming that the date range in your query should be between 2013-08 and not 2013-07). You need to switch the join against purchases to an outer join. This will include members without any purchases so...

```
   left outer JOIN `purchases` `p` ON `m`.`memberId` = `p`.`memberId`
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a8cf/4/0)

Answer (score 0):

(Replacing the inner join with left join you will get the right result)

FROM `db`.`members` `m`
       Left Join `db`.`registration_steps` `r` ON `m`.`memberId` = `r`.`memberId` 
       left join `db`.`purchases` `p` ON `m`.`memberId` = `p`.`memberId`

or you can replace any purchase alone with the left join.

Note: left join and left outer join both are produces the same result so you can use any one of them.